# Correct way of memory management using Emgu CV 3.1

Tags: c#, emgucv, flood-fill

My background is C++ and I have been trying to translate one of my apps that uses OpenCV to a C# app that uses EmguCV. I have read the EmguCV documentation and Wiki as well as StackOverflow Q/As as deeply as humanly possible with no luck in solving some of the basic problems. At this point I wonder if the way I think about EmguCV is fundamentally flawed.

I was under the impression that when EmguCV has provided an interface to the C++ library for let's say `FloodFill` using `CvInvoke.FloodFill(IInputOutputArray, IInputOutputArray, ...)`, underneath it takes care of its own memory management to the point that the returning `IInputOutputArray`s (in my case a `Mat`) is all taken care of. In practice however, A call to `CvInvoke.FloodFill` fails with an exception from within the dll.

This is what I have:

```
int i = ...
int j = ...
int intensity = ...
int height = img.Rows;
int width = img.Cols;
Mat outputMask = new Mat(height + 2, width + 2, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
Rectangle dummy = new Rectangle();
CvInvoke.FloodFill(img, outputMask, new Point(i, j), new MCvScalar(255), out dummy, new MCvScalar(intensity), new MCvScalar(intensity), Connectivity.EightConnected, FloodFillType.MaskOnly);
```

But the call fails with an exception description that is not helpful. I have used `GCHandle` allocation and pinning for other methods to be able to access the raw data underneath, but I believe `CvInvoke.FloodFill` should be safe when called on some local `Mat`s.

My question is whether I'm completely off track with the way EmguCV is supposed to be used given my background with C++ and OpenCV. If so, what is the correct way of calling such function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone who may find themselves having the same problem with EmguCV 3.1 FloodFill. After debugging my code for quite a long time, I am convinced that EmguCV 3.1 implementation of `CvInvoke.FloodFill` is buggy. There was no way to get a mask out of that method using `FloodFillType.MaskOnly` flag.

Instead I ended up editing my original image to have values between `0` and `254`, then did a normal FloodFill using fill value of `255`. Then used `Image.InRange()` method to separate all `255` (filled) pixels from the original image. I will report the bug to EmguCV team and see what happens.